# How to vary the class of a TD on MVC3 WebGrid generated output?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am using the MVC3 WebGrid (Razor) and everything is working fine.  However, I need to vary the css class that is attached to a particular column based on the value that is in the column.

I have a non-Server-side JQuery way of doing this already.  There are a few reasons why I want this to happen outside of JQuery.

Basically, I'm doing cell traffic-lighting/highlighting based on the value of the cell.  So if the value in the cell is "62.5", the class that needs to be attached to the `<td>` is `scr60`.  This sets the background-color for the cell to the appropriate shade.

```
<tr>
  <td class="scr60">62.5</td>
</tr>
```

I know I can control the output of the **contents** of the cell using the `format:` parameter on the `grid.Column()` definition, but I need to set the CSS class for the actual `<td>` that contains the contents (so that the entire cell is highlighted, not just the value/content itself.

I already have a separate helper class/method to output the name of the CSS class I want to use, based on the value.  What I need is a way to adjust the style of the containing `<td>` using the output of that method.

Again, **I already have a JQuery solution that does this**, I'm looking for a way to do this with the webgrid itself.

Comment: I tried playing around with the WebGrid and couldn't find a solution for you. There is a "style" property on grid.Column, but from what I can tell it sets the style for the entire column, not the individual cell.

Comment: thanks anyway Sam.  I'm afraid I may need to look at another grid (MvcContrib Grid?) or just do it in a table to get what I need/want.

Comment: I ended up using google.visualization.data Table chart visualizations.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with WebGrid you can't do this BUT you can include a `span` within the "cell" and add your class(es) to the `span` based on whatever condition you want.

Answer (score -1):

Like the 'format:' parameter, there is a 'style:' parameter which you can use like this:

```
style: "class1 class2"
```

Comment: Pretty certain that style: is only available at the column level, not the cell level;